# How can I apply a saved configuration

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on an admin page and so far I've only worked on PHP and a bit of HTML. But now, I have run into a problem, what I would like to know is how I could apply this configuration automatically through HTML as shown in the following script:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_SESSION['userID']))
{
    $sql_result=$db->ExecuteQuery("SELECT `admin_set` FROM `users` WHERE `id`={$_SESSION['userID']}");
    if($sql_result!=false)
    {
        //exit("Ok");
        $j_settings=$sql_result->fetch_assoc()['admin_set'];
        $_SESSION['admin_set']=$j_settings;
        include_once("./classes/admin_settings.class.php");
        $settings=new AdminSettings((string)$j_settings);
        //echo '<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="path/to/your/file.js"> sidebarColor('.') </script>';
    }
  }

function GetThemeKey(int $index) : string
{
    switch($index)
    {
      case 0:
        return "primary";
      case 1:
        return "dark";
      case 2:
        return "info";
      case 3:
        return "success";
      case 4:
        return "warning";
      case 5:
        return "danger";
      default:
        return "primary";
    }
}
?>
<div class="card-body pt-sm-3 pt-0">
<!-- Sidebar Backgrounds -->
<div>
  <h6 class="mb-0">Sidebar Colors</h6>

</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="switch-trigger background-color">
  <div class="badge-colors my-2 text-start">
  <span class="badge filter bg-gradient-primary<?=($settings->HighlightColor==0? ' active':'')?>" data-color="primary" onclick="sidebarColor(this)"></span>
  <span class="badge filter bg-gradient-dark<?=($settings->HighlightColor==1? ' active':'')?>" data-color="dark" onclick="sidebarColor(this)"></span>
  <span class="badge filter bg-gradient-info<?=($settings->HighlightColor==2? ' active':'')?>" data-color="info" onclick="sidebarColor(this)"></span>
  <span class="badge filter bg-gradient-success<?=($settings->HighlightColor==3? ' active':'')?>" data-color="success" onclick="sidebarColor(this)"></span>
  <span class="badge filter bg-gradient-warning<?=($settings->HighlightColor==4? ' active':'')?>" data-color="warning" onclick="sidebarColor(this)"></span>
  <span class="badge filter bg-gradient-danger<?=($settings->HighlightColor==5? ' active':'')?>" data-color="danger" onclick="sidebarColor(this)"></span>
 </div>
</a>
<!-- Sidenav Type -->
<div class="mt-3">
  <h6 class="mb-0">Sidenav Type</h6>
  <p class="text-sm">Choose between 2 different sidenav types.</p>
</div>
<div class="d-flex">
  <button class="btn bg-gradient-dark px-3 mb-2 active" data-class="bg-gradient-dark" onclick="sidebarType(this)">Dark</button>
  <button class="btn bg-gradient-dark px-3 mb-2 ms-2" data-class="bg-transparent" onclick="sidebarType(this)">Transparent</button>
  <button class="btn bg-gradient-dark px-3 mb-2 ms-2" data-class="bg-white" onclick="sidebarType(this)">White</button>
</div>
<p class="text-sm d-xl-none d-block mt-2">You can change the sidenav type just on desktop view.</p>
<!-- Navbar Fixed -->
<div class="mt-3 d-flex">
  <h6 class="mb-0">Navbar Fixed</h6>
  <div class="form-check form-switch ps-0 ms-auto my-auto">
    <input class="form-check-input mt-1 ms-auto" type="checkbox" id="navbarFixed" onclick="navbarFixed(this)">
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="horizontal dark my-3">
<div class="mt-2 d-flex">
  <h6 class="mb-0">Sidenav Mini</h6>
  <div class="form-check form-switch ps-0 ms-auto my-auto">
    <input class="form-check-input mt-1 ms-auto" type="checkbox" id="navbarMinimize" onclick="navbarMinimize(this)">
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="horizontal dark my-3">
<div class="mt-2 d-flex">
  <h6 class="mb-0">Light / Dark</h6>
  <div class="form-check form-switch ps-0 ms-auto my-auto">
    <input class="form-check-input mt-1 ms-auto" type="checkbox" id="dark-version" onclick="darkMode(this)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Currently, what this script does is load a sidebar on the right that is displayed when a button is pressed. Specifically, my problem is that I want it to automatically apply the saved color when this element is loaded as well as make it change color when I click on one of the options and call the ***sidebarColor(this)*** function in a *JavaScript* file:

[Pink color image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYB0A.jpg)

[Blue color image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1iRS.jpg)

But if I refresh the page this color goes back to color 0 (pink). In the tests that I am doing, I have a PHP class called Admin Settings where I am setting the color 4 (orange) by default, as you can see in the previous code, I have modified the HTML so that the color is selected in the buttons based on this new default value and when I refresh the page, this button is correctly selected. But this color is not automatically applied on the page:

[Problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7oqe.jpg)

So my question is: **Where and how would I have to apply the *sidebarColor()* function so that it is called automatically when the element loads?**

***sidebarColor*** function:

```
function sidebarColor(a) {
  var parent = a.parentElement.children;
  var color = a.getAttribute("data-color");

  for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
    parent[i].classList.remove('active');
  }

  if (!a.classList.contains('active')) {
    a.classList.add('active');
  } else {
    a.classList.remove('active');
  }

  var sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidenav');
  sidebar.setAttribute("data-color", color);

  if (document.querySelector('#sidenavCard')) {
    var sidenavCard = document.querySelector('#sidenavCard');
    let sidenavCardClasses = ['card', 'card-background', 'shadow-none', 'card-background-mask-' + color];
    sidenavCard.className = '';
    sidenavCard.classList.add(...sidenavCardClasses);

    var sidenavCardIcon = document.querySelector('#sidenavCardIcon');
    let sidenavCardIconClasses = ['ni', 'ni-diamond', 'text-gradient', 'text-lg', 'top-0', 'text-' + color];
    sidenavCardIcon.className = '';
    sidenavCardIcon.classList.add(...sidenavCardIconClasses);
  }
}
```

Comment: Well can you show what the `sidebarColor` function does? Do you save the settings anywhere, maybe that function has a bug? Is `$settings->HighlightColor` applied correctly for styling the left hand navigation? It's hard to tell, you have really many questions in one.

Comment: If I may take a guess: You call `sidebarColor` just somewhere before the closing body tag.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I just added the sidebarColor function. Regarding the function, it does not have any bugs and it is well implemented when interacting with the buttons. What I want to know is what should I put so that I can call this sidebarColor() function automatically when I load the script.

Comment: Well it seems you have commented out where you call it. Just put the call in a script tag in the HTML. We don't see what the function does so we cannot tell you when to best call it. It seems you also have another problem. Your script tag: `<script ...  src="path/to/your/file.js"> sidebarColor('.') </script>`. You must *either* put an `src` **or** code inside the script tag, **not** both!

Comment: That commented line was a test I did on another forum, it's unrelated. This script is actually a separate php snippet that is included along with others to form a web page, this script is called by another parent as a module, so it should work like the others.

Comment: Thanks for the details. But so what happens when you call the function? Your code doesn't show where you tried to call it. What happend? Are there errors in the browser console? You have to understand the function is an implementation only known to you so we cannot judge the "where to call this function" part.

Comment: I will explain it to you in another way, surely this way you will understand me better:
This settings option where the colors are, let's imagine I want to change a color and save it to the database. I don't know how to do it through javascript and php.
(1/2)

Comment: What I did was that I created a class in php to handle the settings data and be able to collect them in json format through the database, and I managed to apply this choice to the buttons, but I tried to call it through a <script > to the same javascript function that is in the onclick event of the buttons, but it does not react and therefore does not apply the saved color. Currently I deleted that <script> because it didn't seem to work, that's why it's not in the post. (2/2)

Comment: Don't explain to me in the comments - explain in your question text. No one will read 20 conversations from us until you explain what you need. Just update the question text directly.

Comment: You are basically saying you don't save the value at all? Well then why are you asking "where to call this function" when you know the value isn't saved in the first place? I think you should retry making your real problem clear.